# scala sbt: how to find out and download dependencies automatically just like go get?

Tags: scala, sbt

As known, in golang, `go get dir/...` would find out and download all dependencies of package specified by dir.

Then in scala, does sbt provide similar function? So that we don't need to add dependencies into build file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid the scala sbt doesn't provide the exact kind of feature you are looking. However, sbt does provide several ways to automate the process of downloading dependencies. The closest technique related to your use case would be using **ivy configuration and setting files**.
You can read about that here:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html